# Getting 401: Unauthorized response when querying groups endpoint of Azure AD Graph API

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a .Net Core 2.0 application with an app registration in Azure.

I need to determine if the signed-in user is a member of a specific Azure AD Group. I also need to retrieve the Group's ID using only the Group's name.

In order to retrieve the group ID, I am issuing an `HttpWebRequest` to

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/groups?api-version=1.6&$filter=displayName eq 'My group name'
```

I am passing in a valid access token.  I say it is valid because I am successfully retrieving data from the Power BI API using this token.

Every time I execute this request, I get a `401: Unauthorized` response back.

The app registration has the following delegated Azure AD Graph API permissions: `Read all users' basic profiles`, `Read all groups`, and `Read directory data`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the token works on the Power BI REST API, then it certainly will not work on the Azure AD Graph API.

Access tokens in Azure AD only work on a single API, identified by the audience (aud) claim in the token.

You will need to get another token for Azure AD Graph API using the resource `https://graph.windows.net` when acquiring the token.

The API you are using is Azure AD Graph API, not Microsoft Graph API.
MS Graph API has the resource identifier `https://graph.microsoft.com`, and is accessed via `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

[MS Graph API Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)

Comment: Thanks @juunas for that clarification. I have modified the name of API in the question and tags, and will try your suggestion to get a separate access token for the Azure AD Graph API.  I assumed that I only needed one access token for any Azure services, but this is the first time I am accessing more than one API from my application.

Comment: I ended up switching to the Microsoft Graph API because that's what Microsoft recommends.

Comment: True, AAD Graph is being deprecated. Though a bunch of stuff from there is still under the beta endpoint of MS Graph.